# Auxiliary Typeclasses in Lean

Tags: lean, lean4, lean-mathlib

It's a common theme in Mathlib to use some auxiliary typeclass to define the one we actually want to use. For example, to define `PseudoMetricSpace` we use the typeclass `Dist` given by the following:

```
@[ext]
class Dist (α : Type _) where
  dist : α → α → ℝ
```

From what I understand this definition of `Dist` doesn't come with any of the properties we'd like to be associated with a pseudometric. We then let `PseudoMetricSpace` be an extension of `Dist` where `dist` has all the desired properties. My question is what was the point of starting with the typeclass `Dist`? I.e., couldn't we just include the definition of `dist` with type `α → α → ℝ` inside `PseudoMetricSpace` and take it along with any further extensions (say, to `MetricSpace`)?

My intuition is that it probably helps establish a nice base for anything that needs a `dist` function. Right or wrong, can you give an example of why this auxiliary `Dist` is necessary/appealing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done so that formalization matches mathematical practice. Defining *only* `PseudoMetricSpace` directly with `dist` would correspond to the real-life situation where, as soon as you called a map “distance” everyone would jump in your face and demand that you do not utter another sentence until you prove it really has the required properties of a distance. You would not be allowed to say “let me just prove a lemma first”.

The phenomenon is more visible when a standard notion is associated with standard notation (which it is not for distance). For example, if you use the symbol $\leq$, most people will assume that it denotes (at least) a preorder, but will allow you to postpone the proof. This is precisely how mathlib treats the situation: it has the type class `LE` which is used to introduce the symbol `≤`, and another type class `Preorder` which extends `LE` by the properties of a preorder.

More generally, formalized mathematics exposes all sorts of social conventions and makes them explicit. Of course, you can think of them as "clever engineering".

Comment: It also seems that from a formalization point of view, sticking to this approach of having a hierarchy of structures consisting of many small steps of generalization and making definitions/theorems at the highest level of generality possible makes for more robust developments, because following it makes it easier to come back and change a hierarchy of structures after the fact.

Comment: I see, so the point is that `Dist` claims the name `dist` and primes us for introducing a `dist` with all the right properties of a pseudometric? This allows us to separate the claim and the demonstration of its properties?

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand: Of course there will be additional benefits of good engineering.

Comment: @AlexByard: precisely.